# Using regular expressions in JAVA how do i say 4 any letter a space and then 4 numbers

Tags: java, regex, expression

What I want is a class code like `ACCT 4838`.

I tried

```
String REGEX = "[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][\\s][\\d][\\d][\\d][\\d]";
String REGEX = "[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]\\s\\d\\d\\d\\d"
```

I apologize if this gets flagged i have been looking around for a while and i cant quite peg what it is im doing wrong. should be a quick one for someone.

Comment: I do not use java, but this should be the regex `^[a-zA-Z]{4}\s\d{4}$`

Comment: @ArghyaC is right, just that the Java equivalent does not need `^$`. Using `"[a-zA-Z]{4}\\s\\d{4}"` should be fine. Also see [this](https://regex101.com/r/iS3tR9/1).

Comment: You can use online tester tools like http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html to debug your regex ;)

Comment: @ArghyaC well, technically you cannot use `\s` since it allows tabs and OP wants a single space.

Comment: @FedericoPiazza Yes, `\s` will include all types of `space`, `[a-zA-Z]{4} \d{4}` should do. By the way, op has answered his own question :)

Comment: quick follow up. say my input string is "ACCT 4404 The Quick Brown Fox" How do I say (using ^[a-zA-Z]{4}\\s\\d{4}) If the first part matches its good. Cause currently it comes back false because its comparing that pattern but wont ignore the rest of the string. Basically what do I add the regex to add match this and be indifferent to the remaining characters (however many there may be)

Comment: the following worked ^[a-zA-Z]{4}\\s\\d{4}(.*)

Comment: @BoomerAndZiggy, `\d` is just an equivalent of `[0-9]`, but `[\d]` is nothing.  Your regexp is correct, but for this little detail.  The same applies to `\s`, it is an equivalent to `[\t\ ]`, but `[\s]` is nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regex like this:

```
(?i)^[a-z]{4} \d{4}$   // With inline insensitive flag
^[A-Za-z]{4} \d{4}$    // without inline flag
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Remember to escape backslashes in java like `^[A-Za-z]{4} \\d{4}$`

**[IdeOne example](https://ideone.com/rjyfLX)**

Answer (score 0):

Below works. In java the single \ gives an error. I was stupidly feeding in the wrong string in addition to not having the proper code.

String REGEX = "^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]\s\d\d\d\d";